# Runing apt update && apt install -y sudo in a container fails

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker, ubuntu, debian

I am trying to standup this container in Ubuntu 16.04 and one of the steps is: `RUN apt update && apt install -y sudo`

This step fails withh `Temporary failure to resolve` some repos. This is the output of this error:

```
Step 2/8 : RUN apt update && apt install -y sudo
 ---> Running in 15215f43b522

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface yet. Use with caution in scripts.

Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease

Err http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease

Err http://apt.postgresql.org jessie-pgdg InRelease

Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease

Err http://apt.postgresql.org jessie-pgdg Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'apt.postgresql.org'
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/jessie-pgdg/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/jessie-pgdg/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'apt.postgresql.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
All packages are up to date.

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface yet. Use with caution in scripts.

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package sudo
```

I am able to ping the repos on my host machine. But the above output seems to suggest that these hosts are unpingable from the container that comes up.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems `DNS` cannot be resolved. You can try either of next two solutions:

1. Use `--dns=xx.xx.xx.xx` to start container.

Something like `docker run --dns=xx.xx.xx.xx images`

2. Change `/etc/docker/daemon.json` in host machine and restart the docker daemon after modify.

Add something like following to `daemon.json`:

```
{
    "dns":[xx.xx.xx.xx]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since apt changes its behavior with versions (see description in `man apt`), typing `apt upgrade` in the command line will bring you to the most up-to-date version, and will most likely resolve issues connecting to the repositories. HOWEVER, take these steps to ensure you cover more bases:

1. Add in the apt upgrade to your container
2. Manually install sudo (`apt-get install sudo`)
3. LAST RESORT TO FIX THE DOCKER CONTAINER COMMAND: `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`